# Android or iOS Captive Portal Login Window Auto close on success

Tags: android, ios

currently I'm building a captive Login spalsh page which should just print the terms of use of our internal wlan, so far so good everything works,
however after accepting the terms and having internet access, the client still hangs on the redirects site, thats not really cool, is there a way to automatically close the captive portal login window after a successful connection?
I tried to redirect to the captive portal detection page, however that does not work, is there another way to automatically close the captive portal window?

Edit: Currently I also tried to have a window.close, however that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to close the Captive Browser on iOS. You could whitelist the captive network detection URL, use the DNS-redirect method for captive portals, and avoid the Captive Browser entirely.

On newer versions of Android, Lollipop (5.0) and above, the Captive Browser automatically dismisses itself as soon as it detects full Internet access. So you'll get the behavior you expect from those devices.

Some people don't want Android's new auto-close behavior, but it doesn't appear to be optional.